# Running uwsgi socket only works when I set chmod-socket=666

Tags: python, django, sockets, nginx, uwsgi

Is there any way I can get this socket running in 664?

```
uwsgi --socket /etc/nginx/sites-available/TestServer.sock --wsgi-file TestServer/wsgi.py --chmod-socket=666
```

666 Django runs fine, but 664 and I get a 502 Bad Gateway. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: it probably wont help, but it would be better to place your socket files in /var/run,  like  `/var/run/nginx/TestServer.sock`

Comment: What user you are running uwsgi under, is it in the same group as nginx user?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. The issue turned out to be a user/group issue. Stupid of me.

I do like best practices though, so I'm wondering, how can I move the socket? I know I can't simply copy it.

I have to admit, I'm barely clear on how I created it in the first place. I've been following this tutorial. https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Comment: You can move the socket by changing the socket flag. `uwsgi --socket /path/you/want/socket/in/TestServer.sock --wsgi-file TestServer/wsgi.py --chmod-socket=666` The socket gets created automatically, but does not get removed by default. You'll need to use the `vacuum = true` directive for it to delete the socket when uWSGI stops.

Comment: I'm in the same situation. Could you explain how did you manage to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: @Slbox Please answer your own question. This is showing up as a first hit on google and it's a deadend now.

Comment: I don't have an answer, sorry. All I can recommend is that you check your permissions and maybe try a new user/group as a way to troubleshoot if it comes to that.